# R: Sort multiple columns by another data.frame?

Tags: sorting, r

I'm trying to make sense of how to sort one data.frame based on multiple columns in another.  This question [does this with vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568511/how-do-i-sort-one-vector-based-on-values-of-another).  Can someone suggest a way to do the equivalent with data.frames?

Here's some sample data.

```
x1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=letters[1:5], c=rnorm(5))
x2 <- data.frame(a=c(4,4,2), b=c("d", "d", "b"), d=rnorm(3))
```

So I want to sort x2 by the first two columns of x1.  My actual data is much more complicated, but this replicates the idea...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It really depends on what your data really looks like. As it looks right now, you only need one column to sort, and that is easily done by:

```
x2[order(match(x2[,1],x1[,1])),]
```

If you need more than one column, this becomes a bit trickier. You will have to specify which one you want to sort first on, and which one second, eg :

```
x1 <- data.frame(a=rep(1:3,2), b=rep(letters[2:4],each=2), c=rnorm(6))
x2 <- data.frame(a=c(3,3,2), b=c("c", "d", "b"), d=rnorm(3))


x2[order(match(
  paste(x2[,1],x2[,2]),
  paste(x1[,1],x1[,2]))
),]
```

This sorts on the first column first, and then on the second. You have to keep in mind that you need all combinations in x2 also in x1. T

Answer (score 3):

Attach a rank column to the relevant columns of x1:

```
len <- dim(x1)[1]
x1. <- cbind(x1[,1:2], rank=1:len)
```

Merge into x2 (this is like a SQL join; see the merge documentation for how to specify what happens if there are ambiguities such as multiple matches or no matches):

```
x2. <- merge(x2, x1.)
```

Sort:

```
x2.[order(x2.[,'rank']),]
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done precisely using `plyr`.  Joris' answer would work fairly well, but potentially could missort when combining strings:

```
> paste ("A A","B")
[1] "A A B"
> paste ("A","A B")
[1] "A A B"
```

You can get an exact answer using `join.keys` and `match`:

```
x1 <- data.frame(a=rep(1:3,2), b=rep(letters[2:4],each=2), c=rnorm(6))
x2 <- data.frame(a=c(3,3,2), b=c("c", "d", "b"), d=rnorm(3))

library(plyr)
keys<-join.keys(x1,x2,c("a","b"))
matches<-match(keys$y,keys$x,nomatch=(keys$n+1))
x2[order(matches),]
```

This should handle most edge cases, mismatched list sizes, etc.  Items without a match in both the index columns are put at the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of how to sort a dataframe:

```
> right_join(x1, x2[,1:2], by=c("a","b"))
  a b          c
1 2 b  0.6182433
2 4 d -2.2239003
3 4 d -2.2239003
```