# How do i get coerce the sort command into placing 'ADNP-AS1' after 'ADNP2' instead of the other way around?

Tags: linux, sorting

I'm sorting a text file containing gene expression data, and I need the gene names to be in a certain order for tasks further down the pipeline. I'm using a .sh script to do several tasks, including sorting. Some genes have nearly identical names; a good example is the sequence "ADNP", "ADNP2", "ADNP-AS1". I need the hyphenated gene name to come last when sorted, but right now it goes second.

I had thought that adding the LC_CTYPE="en_us.UTF-8" and LC_COLLATE="en_us.UTF-8" options to sort would fix the problem, since those were the locale options that had worked on a different local machine. However, I keep getting the same results.

I've experimented a bit using echo -e "ADNP ADNP2 ADNP-AS1" | sort with various options on sort. When I do so, I get the correct order. But, when running the shell script (as provided below), I do not. I'll also provide the output of

#### here's an excerpt from the shell script

```
tail -n +2 $tpm | LC_CTYPE=en_us.UTF-8 sort -k1,1 | cut -f 4  > "${wd}/${sample}_host.tmp"
```

#### here are my locale settings

```
locale   
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: good bit of experimenting here. If you're running short on time, I would add a new column with the values reformatted so that the record will sort correctly. You can then strip off that column, or just ignore it in your follow on processing. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I actually ended up adding a line further down our parsing pipeline (in R) based off this code `x2[order(match(x2[,1],x1[,1])),]` that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990155/r-sort-multiple-columns-by-another-data-frame). The solution is just to match each expression set iteratively to a reference gene list.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. If you can make this more of an [mcve] with small sample data set, and required output then  you can answer your own Q and gain valuable reputation points (after 48 hrs?). And learn to use the `{}` tool from the edit menu on selected text to get proper formatting of code/data/errMsgsEtc. Good luck.!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal reproducible example in R:

```
> geneSamp <- c("ADNP", "ADNP-AS1", "ADNP2")
> sampExprVals <- c(10, 20, 0)
> geneDF <- data.frame(geneSamp, sampExprVals)
> correctGeneOrder <- data.frame(a = c("ADNP", "ADNP2", "ADNP-AS1"), b = c(10, 0, 20))
> geneDF <- geneDF[order(match(correctGeneOrder[, 1], geneDF[, 1])),]
> print(geneDF)
  geneSamp sampExprVals
1     ADNP           10
3    ADNP2            0
2 ADNP-AS1           20
```

Unfortunately I still don't know how to fix the root of the problem, but this is a fairly easy workaround that's easy to implement into the parsing loop that we already run.

Answer (score 2):

> using echo -e "ADNP ADNP2 ADNP-AS1" | sort …, I get the correct order.

That's no wonder, since the names are already in the desired order on one single line, and `sort` doesn't change word order within a line. In contrast,

```
echo -e "ADNP\nADNP2\nADNP-AS1"|sort
```

yields the unwanted order

```
ADNP
ADNP-AS1
ADNP2
```

> I still don't know how to fix the root of the problem

If, as in the shown cases, there's a letter after the hyphen, `sort -d` (*consider only blanks and alphanumeric characters*) yields the desired order.

Comment: I did realize after posting that experimenting with sort the way I was wasn't working correctly. Thanks for the fix.